# Simple php command not working?

Tags: php, html

I am following this tutorial on youtube on how to make a contact form (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9KS2QuFXIs8) and im at a part where some of my php code will not run because of ...

```
<?php else: ?>
<p>Thank you for your Message!</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

also

```
<?php if($form_complete === FALSE): ?>
```

The rest of the code below that uses php works so im sure its not the server but maybe the fact the above code has a colon. Here's the rest of the code.

```html
<?php

// Set email variables
$email_to = 'guomonster@gmail.com';
$email_subject = 'Form submission';

// Set required fields
$required_fields = array('fullname','email','comment');

// set error messages
$error_messages = array(
'fullname' => 'Please enter a Name to proceed.',
'email' => 'Please enter a valid Email Address to continue.',
'comment' => 'Please enter your Message to continue.'
);

// Set form status
$form_complete = FALSE;

// configure validation array
$validation = array();

// check form submittal
if(!empty($_POST)) {
// Sanitise POST array
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) $_POST[$key] = remove_email_injection(trim($value));

// Loop into required fields and make sure they match our needs
foreach($required_fields as $field) {
// the field has been submitted?
if(!array_key_exists($field, $_POST)) array_push($validation, $field);

// check there is information in the field?
if($_POST[$field] == '') array_push($validation, $field);

// validate the email address supplied
if($field == 'email') if(!validate_email_address($_POST[$field])) array_push($validation, $field);
}

// basic validation result
if(count($validation) == 0) {
// Prepare our content string
$email_content = 'New Website Comment: ' . "\n\n";

// simple email content
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
if($key != 'submit') $email_content .= $key . ': ' . $value . "\n";
}

// if validation passed ok then send the email
mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_content);

// Update form switch
$form_complete = TRUE;
}
}

function validate_email_address($email = FALSE) {
return (preg_match('/^[^@\s]+@([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,}$/i', $email))? TRUE : FALSE;
}

function remove_email_injection($field = FALSE) {
return (str_ireplace(array("\r", "\n", "%0a", "%0d", "Content-Type:", "bcc:","to:","cc:"), '', $field));
}

?>



<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>

    <title>Contact Form</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <link href="css/contactform.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var nameError = '<?php echo $error_messages['fullname']; ?>';
      var emailError = '<?php echo $error_messages['email']; ?>';
      var commentError = '<?php echo $error_messages['comment']; ?>';
    </script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="formWrap">
      <div id="form">
        <?php if($form_complete === FALSE); ?>
        <form>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="label">
              Your Name
            </div>
            <div class="input">
              <input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname" class="detail" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['fullname'])? $_POST['fullname'] : ''; ?>" />
              <?php if(in_array('fullname', $validation)): ?><span class="error"><?php echo $error_messages['fullname']; ?></span><?php endif; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="context">
              e.g. John Smith
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="label">
              Your Email
            </div>
            <div class="input">
              <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="detail" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['email'])? $_POST['email'] : ''; ?>" />
              <?php if(in_array('email', $validation)): ?><span class="error"><?php echo $error_messages['email']; ?></span><?php endif; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="context">
              We will not share your email.
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="label">
              Your Message
            </div>
            <div class="input">
              <textarea name="comment" id="comment" class="mess"><?php echo isset($_POST['comment'])? $_POST['comment'] : ''; ?></textarea>
              <?php if(in_array('comment', $validation)): ?><span class="error"><?php echo $error_messages['comment']; ?></span><?php endif; ?>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="submit">
            <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Send Message">
            </form>
          </div>
        <?php else: ?>
        <p>Thank you for your Message!</p>
        <?php endif; ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: `if($form_complete === FALSE);` <-- shouldn't that be `:`?

Comment: what version of PHP are you running?

Comment: yes yes i was testing it and it worked but idk if the colon made a different to the code or not

Comment: PHP 7.0 (7.0.13)  VC14 x64 Thread Safe (2016-Nov-09 04:00:53)

Answer (score -3):

In PHP You should use Brackets for conditional codeblocks.

```
<?php if ($form_complete === FALSE) { ?>
<p>if-branch</p>
<?php } else { ?>
<p>Thank you for your Message!</p>
<?php } ?>
```

But using PHP code inside html can be very confusing. Try the following:

```
<?php
if ($form_complete === FALSE) {
  // do something
} else {
  echo '<p>Thank you for your Message!</p>'
}
?>
```

Comment: It's nicer (imo) to do it this way, but it's by no means the way it _has_ to be done.

Comment: Ok, I changed my formulation, but I still think it's not good, to learn the if(): version. In a big project nobody uses this and its even more confusing. Don't get used to it. Just learn the brackets, code clarity is very necessary

Comment: I used the first code and had to edit out the first p and it didnt give me an error but idk if it worked or not. <?php if ($form_complete === FALSE) { ?>
  
  <?php } else { ?>
  <p>Thank you for your Message!</p>
  <?php } ?>